# Azure CLI Windows VM creation os disk size

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-cli, azure-managed-disk

I've been trying to create a Windows Server 2016 VM with an os disk that is less than the default of size 128GB using the azure cli.
Below is a sample of what I've executed with simplified parameter names

```
az vm create  --name 'dWeb02-vm' --resource-group 'dev-rg' --admin-password 'ComplexPassword' --admin-username 'dwebadm' --availability-set 'dev-as' --image 'Win2016Datacenter' --location 'northeurope' --nics 'dev-nic' --size 'Standard_B1ms' --os-disk-size-gb '32' --storage-sku 'StandardSSD_LRS'
```

This results in a VM being created with a managed disk but the size of the disk is 127GB and I get a Resize error on script execution

Deployment error

```
Deployment failed. Correlation ID: 0c0f1476-8464-444e-91e1-52de3631a64f. {
  "status": "Failed",
  "error": {
    "code": "ResourceDeploymentFailure",
    "message": "The resource operation completed with terminal provisioning state 'Failed'.",
    "details": [
      {
        "code": "ResizeDiskError",
        "message": "Resource with id THE RESOURCE ID."
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Is it possible to create an OS disk that is less than 128GB for a windows VM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We actually released a Windows Server Edition that uses a smaller disk instead of the default 128GB. Managed disks cannot be resized down, only up. So if you want to deploy a smaller OS disk on Windows Server you should use any of the images with [smalldisk] in the image name

[image]

If deploying to CLI or PowerShell you can use the following doc to navigate the available images and find the ones that support small disk

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/cli-ps-findimage#navigate-the-images